# Can't send multiple messages via socket

Tags: java, sockets

I'm trying to make a little chat system. I have a console and a client. Right now only the client need to send messages to the console. I can connect successfully to the server, and i can send one message from client to console. The trouble begins after sending the first message. When the first message i can't send any other messages.

I don't know if it's the console that won't read the message or the client that won't send the message. In this case how could i troubleshoot this?

```
public class ClientMainClass {


private static Socket socket;
public static void main(String args[]) {
    try {

        String host = "localhost";
        int port = 25000;
        InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByName(host);
        socket = new Socket(address, port);

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Skriv dit username:");
        String name = scanner.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Du er logget ind som: " + name);
        String input;

        do{
            input = scanner.nextLine();
            if (input.equalsIgnoreCase("exit")) {
                System.out.println("Du forlod serveren");
                socket.close();
                continue;
            }else {
                /*OutputStream os = socket.getOutputStream();
                OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(os);
                BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(osw);*/
                PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(),true);
                Date date = new Date();
                String time = date.getDate()+"/"+date.getMonth()+":"+date.getHours()+":"+date.getMinutes();
                //Send the message to the server
                String message = time+ " - " + name + ": "+input;
                printWriter.println(message);
                System.out.println(message);
                continue;
            }
        }while (!(input.equals("exit")));
    } catch (Exception exception) {
        exception.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        //Closing the socket
        try {
            socket.close();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
}
```

My server:

```
public class Main{

private static Socket socket;

public static void main(String[] args) {


    try {

        int port = 25000;
        ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
        System.out.println("Server Started and listening to the port 25000");

        while(true) {
            //Reading the message from the client
            socket = serverSocket.accept();
            InputStream is = socket.getInputStream();
            InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
            System.out.println(br.readLine());
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            socket.close();
        } catch(Exception e){}
    }
}
}
```

To be clear. I can connect to the server. I can send one message from client to console, but no more than one message.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You never read a second line. Your Server accepts a connection, reads one line from that connection and then waits for a new connection, discarding everything that might arrive at the first connection.

Your client however sends all input using the first (and only) connection, which is absolutely correct.

This specific problem can be solved like this:

```
while(true) {
  //Reading the message from the client
  socket = serverSocket.accept();
  InputStream is = socket.getInputStream();
  InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
  BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
  while(true){
    System.out.println(br.readLine());
  }
}
```

This will cause your program to print everything arriving on that first connection, but it will never accept a second connection.

In order to handle multiple clients, you need a `Thread` to deal with each one.

Comment: Nice, thank you. I moved the socket.accpet() outside the while loop and now it works. Thank you.

Comment: Keep in mind that if you don't call ``accept`` in a loop, your server will only deal with the first connection and never with any additional ones.

Comment: Correct, but right now i only want a one-to-one chat.

Comment: I had a similar problem, and this worked. Thanks!!